# How do I change to dashed lines in manual 97.12?

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

This example is taken from section 97.12 of [the `pgf` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). It explains perfectly what I want to do, but I need the borders of the rectangle made of dashed lines.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{5mm}{5mm}}
   \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{3cm}{2cm}}
   \pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just read the next subsection about `\pgfsetdash`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
\begin{pgfpicture}
  \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{5mm}{5mm}}
  \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{3cm}{2cm}}
  \pgfsetdash{{3pt}{2pt}}{0pt}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The same in TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[
    rounded corners=5mm,
    dash pattern=on 3pt off 2pt,
  ] (0, 0) rectangle (3, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```